# Grammar help on "how...."

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, bare-infinitives

I wish to write a sentence to ask:

> How does the weight of a car `affect` the speed of it?

Should I have `affects` or `affect` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any clause no more than one verb<sup>†</sup> can be inflected for tense, person and number, and that one verb must be the first in the chain.

In your example the first verb in the chain is the auxiliary *do*, and that is inflected; auxiliary *do* always takes an infinitive as its complement, so *affect* is what you want.

---

<sup>†</sup>Except in cases where two or more inflected verbs are conjoined with *and* or *but* or *(n)either..(n)or*. Here the conjoined verbs co-occupy the same syntactic position and role, so the "rule" holds.

Answer (score 0):

The verb phrase is "does affect".  "How" is a placeholder for a (singular) fact, and "does" is the matching third-person singular verb.